# Grub Bootloader error every second boot

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot

Every time I turn on my laptop I get a grub bootloader error. Then I press <kbd>CTRL-ALT-DELETE</kbd> to restart. After it restarts, the grub boot loader is working.

This has happened since I upgraded a Windows 7 partition to Windows 8. Grub still calls it Windows 7(now changed the name to windwows 8).

I get this error:

```
error: no such device: d1b5f862-f834-4269-8d44-c7a70e24c9f4
grub rescue>
```

Comment: Please update your question with the error you get (the text that appears on screen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused because on MSI ONC with a raid 0 on ssd. The raid did not take the boot loader just redirected to an HD which did not start up fast enough causing the error.